# How can we implement future or split payment using Braintree?

Tags: braintree

We are working on one website solution for which we require to implement future and/or split payment using the Braintree payment gateway. Is it any possible solution for the same? How can it be implemented?

We also tried to create sub-merchant for splitting a payment but we are getting the following error.

"Master merchant account ID is invalid.".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braintree does not offer a marketplace/split-payment function. You would only be able to apply for/use Braintree Direct and any funds would go directly to your bank account. There is no ability to have sub-merchants.

Similarly, PayPal has deprecated their original split-payment/pay-forwarding solution.

I suggest you go with PayPal Marketplace.

PayPal Marketplace is an entirely separate solution and you would need to speak with the PayPal team for specific details.